# Bind html variable to typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

This is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <ngx-one-column-layout>
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-one-column-layout>
  `,
})
export class PagesComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    console.log(this.translate.instant('adminPanel'));
  }

  menu = MENU_ITEMS;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    MENU_ITEMS[0]["title"]= this.translate.instant('adminPanel');
    this.menu = MENU_ITEMS;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, but changing the `menu` variable when I overwrite it does not change in the html until I exit the page and re-enter, indicating that it was changed late and does not support the change dynamically. I tried to assign an EventEmitter to the nb menu, but can't, since I can't enter the `nb-menu` to change it from the inside because it's a null-shaped tag (a frame I downloaded it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign value as

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    MENU_ITEMS[0]["title"]= this.translate.instant('adminPanel');
    this.menu = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MENU_ITEMS));
  }
```

For array with objects, angular wont be able to detect changes. So, you need to provide new array as `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MENU_ITEMS))`